# bootstrap-tokenfield does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using bootstrap-tokenfield to display list of color, I declared the necessary library JS and CSS but it does not work:

[image: Result]

Script:

```
//$('#myfiltre').tokenfield();
$('#myfiltre').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
```

Markup (in `index.html`):

```
<div class="space">
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" class="form-control" id="myfiltre" />
    <a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.css">

<script src="public/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
<script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: the problem is ican't show the list when onfocus, autocomplete does not work !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just we need Jquery-ui.css it's necessary to display that source list ..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the import order - Import your tokenfield script after the JQuery.